# How to check if a value already exist in list box before adding to it in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listbox

how can I check if the value is already present in a list-box, so that I can avoid duplicates?

I've added some values to the server-side list-box already, and when I add to list I get more duplicates.

How do I avoid duplicates?

```
lst_Viewers.Items.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
```

Comment: Maybe clear list box before add? Then you never will get neither duplicated nor out-of-date items.

Comment: @abatishchev this is not what Murthy wants.He wants to add items to the list box before checking the duplicate value.

Answer (score 7):

```
ListItem item = new ListItem(reader["Name"].ToString());
if ( ! lst_Viewers.Items.Contains(item) ){
    lst_Viewers.Items.Add(item);
}
```

or

```
var name = reader["Name"].ToString();
ListItem item = lst_Viewers.Items.FindByText(name);
if ( item  == null ){
    lst_Viewers.Items.Add(new ListItem(name));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!lst_Viewers.Items.Any(item => item.Value.ToString().Equals(reader["Name"].ToString())
    lst_Viewers.Items.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be to insert all the values into a `List<string>` then add the items only after the loop, using `.Distinct()` to get only unique values:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())
    names.Add(reader["Name"].ToString())
names.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(name => lst_Viewers.Items.Add(name));
```

This way you don't have to search the whole DropDown in every iteration - more elegant (in my opinion) and more efficient.